# can't find logging message in gae admin console

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, web2py

I deployed a web2py app on gae.
    for logging,
    *.copied "logging.example.conf" and renamed it to "logging.conf"

```
*.added myapp to [loggers]
[loggers]
keys=root,rocket,markdown,web2py,rewrite,app,welcome,myapp

*.added [logger_myapp]
[logger_myapp]
level=WARNING
qualname=web2py.app.myapp
handlers=consoleHandler
propagate=0

*.imported logging in controller(default.py)
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("web2py.app.myapp")
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

*.logged in index():
logger.warn('logging test')
```

but, I can't find this logging message in gae admin console. is there something that I missed??

Comment: There are two logs sections 'admin logs' and logging which once did you use?

Comment: "I failed logging on gae" - what did you try, and what happened? What did you expect to happen? Where is the code?